# Archimedean property

Tags: real-analysis

How can we understand where to apply the Archimedean property of real numbers for a proof or a problem ?

Comment: Please edit the body of your Question to complete the statement of the problem you would like help with.  Currently the body consists only of one sentence fragment.

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me out .

Comment: Please review [ask] for future posts.  Compare your brief post to [this similar previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428274/archimedean-property-the-use-of-the-property-in-basic-real-anaysis-proofs) to get an idea of the level of detail Readers will find useful in trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n=0$, for example. You need to have some $n_0$ such that $\frac 1 n<\varepsilon$ when $n\geq n_0$. But $\frac 1{n_0}<\varepsilon$ if and only if $n_0\varepsilon > 1$. Why does such positive integer exist?

Comment: Thanks...but how do we get to understand where should we apply it in intuitive proofs or elementary problems ?

Comment: @Soham Sarkar, most of the time you will just use it without mentioning it or even paying attention. I'm not sure what you are confused about exactly, there is no "setup to build" for it, you either encounter it, like in my example, or you don't.

Comment: If we consider an example on sequence of functions : 'Let fn(x) = f(x+ 1/x),x€R,n€N . Then,prove that the sequence {fn(x)} is uniformly convergent on R. ' In this problem,to prove the result,we use the definition of uniform continuity and then apply Archimedean property...how do we understand that we have to use this property after using the definition of uniform continuity...it seems a little bit intuitive and dicey .

Comment: @Soham Sarkar, the sequence you wrote is probably not what you wanted...

Comment: I am sorry...I didn't get you .

Comment: @Soham Sarkar, $ f_n(x) = f(x+ 1/x)$ is constant sequence...

Comment: Sorry...my mistake the sequence is fn(x) = f (x + 1/n),x €R and n € N

Comment: @Soham Sarkar, please add all the details if you want any answers. For example, your claim doesn't work for $f(x) = 1$ for $x>0$, and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. You are missing conditions on $f$. I could go about guessing, but really, its up to you to be as precise as you can be. Just a friendly tip, asking vague sequence of questions opposed to precisely stating what you want to know in your question won't get you far on this site.

Comment: Qs." Let f be uniformly continuous on R . For each natural number n , let fn(x) = f(x + 1/n) , x€R . Prove that the sequence {fn(x)} is uniformly convergent on R."

Comment: In that case the answer is obvious. What you want is to find $n$ (independent of $x$) such that $|f(x+\frac 1n)-f(x)| < \varepsilon$. Well, the only clue we have is uniform continuity of $f$, thus there exists $\delta$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$ implies that $|f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$. Setting $y = x + \frac 1n$, we see that we need $\frac 1 n<\delta$ in order to get $|f(x+\frac 1n)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$. Again, just as in my answer, it is painfully obvious that Archimedean property is needed. I still don't understand what is your trouble with it, @Soham Sarkar.

Comment: Do we understand that just because we have to set some upper bound of 1/n ?